# Inno Setup script: Identifier expected error

Tags: inno-setup

Please help me with the following code:

```
[Code]
var
    AppVersionNumber: Integer;
    DBVersionNumber: Integer;
function GetAppVersion:Integer;
    var
        AppVersion: AnsiString;
    begin
        ExtractTemporaryFile('info.dat');
        LoadStringFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\info.dat'), AppVersion);
        AppVersionNumber := StrToInt(Copy(AppVersion, 1, 6));
        DBVersionNumber := StrToInt(Copy(AppVersion, 7, 12));
        GetAppVersion := AppVersionNumber; <== here is error
    end;
```

I don't understand what's wrong here. The Inno setup says there is "Identifier expected" error. If I try to replace on this line GetAppVersion to Result (why? I don't know but I saw it in examples) it says that "Invalid prototype for GetAppVersion".

What's wrong with this code? Please help

Comment: Should work with `Result :=`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Result :=` is needed to specify the result/return value of a function (you don't assign it to the function name like VB)

The "Invalid Prototype" error is most likely because you're using it in a `{code:...}` constant that requires the called function to have a single string parameter at all times.
Try using this taken from [the help file](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptconstants.htm):

```
function GetAppVersion(Param: String): String;
```

Comment: But my function doesn't have any parameters, how it should look?

Comment: Exactly, if using it from a `{code:...}` constant, it MUST have a single string parameter and return a string, as per the help article I linked to. If you're not using a `{code:...}` constant, then trying showing us the code that is now failing and the code that calls it.

Comment: Yeah, you are absolutely right. I thought those functions are like usual ones, but they are not. It's really stupid that you can't return anything else than string or boolean. But now it can be compiled at least. Thanks

Comment: Why? it takes a string in (by virtue of it coming from a script) and is used as a string in the same context. This design is explicitly called out in the help file.